# Is there a way to colorize comments/code in Sweave?

Tags: r, sweave

I found that I can keep comments in the Sweave code chunks by specifying keep.source in the \SweaveOpts, but is there a way to make the code listing look nice like with grayed out comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options illustrated at Vanderbilt University's Department of Biostatistics sweave templates site: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/SweaveTemplate

I found the Sweavel style to be the most flexible.

The [highlight package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highlight/index.html) is another option.

Answer (score 3):

the `pgfSweave` package can produce syntax-highlighted code.